# Angular directive scopes with Typescirpt

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, typescript

I have several buttons on my view and each of them has three states: active, inactive, hover. These are displayed as images. 
I have FooController:

```
foo.controller("FooController", function($scope: IFooScope) {
    // Tell the view about the classes in the app
    this.UnitType = UnitType;
    this.ImageType = ImageType;
    $scope.design = new FooDesign();
});
```

And an interface (FooDesign is just a class that has unitType property):

```
interface IFooScope extends ng.IScope { 
    design: FooDesign;

    setUnitType(unitType: UnitType);
    getUnitTypeImageUrl(unitType: UnitType);   
}
```

And I would like to have a directive  that has html template like this:

```
<div class="unit-type-button">
    <unit-type-image unit-type="UnitType.Millimeters">
    </unit-type-image>
</div>

<div class="unit-type-button">
    <unit-type-image unit-type="UnitType.Inches">
    </unit-type-image>
</div>
```

And in the scope.design there is a unitType property, which must be changed when clicking on these buttons. So if the scope.design.unitType = Millimeters, then that button has active image (eg. unit_type_millimeters_active.png) and other button has inactive image (eg. unit_type_inches_inactive.png) and both also have hover image (eg. unit_type_millimeters_hover.png).

My directive is like this:

```
class UnitTypeImage implements ng.IDirective {
    constructor(private imageService: ImageService) { }

    restrict = "E";
    replace = true;
    template = '<img ng-click=setUnitType(unitType) src="{{getUnitTypeImageUrl(unitType)}}"/>';
    /*scope = {
        unitType: '=';
    };*/

    link = (scope: IFooScope, element, attrs) => {
        scope.setUnitType = function (unitType: UnitType) {
            scope.design.unitType = unitType;
        }

        scope.getUnitTypeImageUrl = function (unitType: UnitType) {
            return (unitType === scope.design.unitType) ? imageService.getUnitTypeImage(unitType, ImageType.Active) : imageService.getUnitTypeImage(unitType, ImageType.Inactive);
        }
    }

    static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        var directive = (imageService: ImageService) => new UnitTypeImage(imageService);
        directive.$inject = ['imageService'];
        return directive;
    }
}
foo.directive('unitTypeImage', UnitTypeImage.factory());
```

If I uncomment scope in the directive then the scope.design is undefined. If I leave it commented then unitType for each function parameter is undefined.

Also, I haven't included hover image functionality here yet and I'm unsure how to do it. One option is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ook3a8Lz/ but I have about a 100 different buttons in the view (not visible at the same time, depends on previous selections) so this would be a mess and I would like to use enumerators when fetching the correct image.

I'm kind of stuck with this so every piece of help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I ditched the IFooScope and made it a service so there's no scope mixups. 
Also, since the directive has unitType in it's scope(with an =) there is no need for unitType in function parameters since they can be accessed now (when IFooScope is no more) by scope.unitType.